# Pure python as backend web application

Tags: python, flask

i have some confusion in web app.
I want to know if we can use pure python without frameworks to build web application(backend).

Comment: Pure Python without frameworks will work. It is very educational but it takes a lot more time to write bug-free, readable web app.
There is a one-time overhead in learning to use a framework, but for those who build apps for a living, using a framework like Django or Flask is many times faster in writing bug-free and very readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, all of the frameworks for building python web apps are built with python.  So you could in theory build yourself a brand new framework.  The real question is why

but here is some info on 'pure' python web apps.

[WSGI](https://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably can since libraries and frameworks like Django and Flask have been created by people like yourself using Python.

The question would be why.

You will have to handle all http requests and communications and that's only the beginning. You will have to right many lines of code to do the job of a few existing functions or classes in Django.

Then there is the matter of security. In a framework like django, that has been around for a while, many security issues have been pointed out and been taken care of. Whereas a freshly written code than handles everything itself, is untested and might be exposed.